# is it possible to tell if DOM was modified, and which part?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

Are there any practical ways to tell what part of the DOM was modified if you know that it will be modified?

I am writing a plugin that will be running along with javascript that i did not write. an event will be triggered before DOM is modified, and one event will be triggered after the modification. It is my job to decide what was changed. is this possible, and if so what is the least horrible way to do this?

Comment: this is an interesting question.  No good way, nor a decent way.  My first idea was to make a copy of all the dom objects in your "before change" event, and then in your "after change" event do a compare of the current dom objects with what you had made a copy of.  This option is plausible if you have a known list of dom objects that could be changed, and you have a limited number of changes your expecting.  Even if, this is an ugly solution and wouldn't recommend it, but it is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: You could write code that would compute an aggregate hash value of the sub-DOM at each node (based on whatever you care about in the DOM). It's important that the hash at each node be a function of the node *and* the subtree. Then you can track changes by checking first to see whether hash codes have changed.

Comment: In what structure would you hope to see the changed DOM? A string? An array of [new] top-level nodes? The top-most node whose subtree was modified? Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: any format. i think the best would be a reference to a DOM node that is a parent of all modified DOM nodes (as low in the tree as possible)  obviously you could just return document, but that wouldnt cut it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in any **practical manner**

Comment: It is possible with DOM mutation events in all major browsers except IE <= 8.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the browser support you need, you may be able to use [DOM mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents).

Answer (score 1):

A possibility, if you know what aspect of the DOM elements are to be modified, is to store the value of that attribute in a .data() node for each element on page load, then compare after the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a hash of the page text (e.g. complete source string) and compare it (on change) to current hash.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you could trigger :animated filter to search the elements being animated, i don't know if you will have so much delay between these kind of events, but if main trigger on initial transform is triggered just when transformation is initiated you could try to catch :animated element and capture initial state before ending animation, then on end capture state and compare, its only a hint i don't have any demonstration or way to reproduce your working environment but i hope this guideline could give you a idea.