# Is there a document.onmodification event or similar?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there an event in JavaScript that fires whenever an element is added/removed/modified?

Not very much detail, but it's a simple question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to tell if DOM was modified, and which part?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510057/is-it-possible-to-tell-if-dom-was-modified-and-which-part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DOM mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) are available in the current version of all major browsers, although not all events are implemented in all browsers. In particular, the catch-all `DOMSubtreeModified` is not available in all browsers. However, `DOMNodeRemoved` and `DOMNodeInserted` are both well supported.

Some caveats:

- IE <= 8 has no support for these events.
- In WebKit, all these events are asynchronous within editable content (i.e. using `contenteditable` or `designMode`)

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla has a nice list of these types of events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events